# Can I extract R and S from an ECDSA signature in bit form, and vica versa?

Tags: dsa, openssl

I have searched the forum and found related information, but not answer to this question. I am working in an extremely bandwidth-restricted environment, in need of creating as small ECDSA signatures as possible. We are, for now, using OpenSSL. Also - as the signature data must be of a predictable length - a fixed size.

I understand that the ECDSA signature consists of two integers S and R, of the bit length equal to the curve size. In addition, 6-7 bytes seem to be added when I try creating a signature, reading the size from `cygwin wc -c` command. I have read many places that this overhead may vary - hence we lose the predictability of the signature length.

Possible solution - extract S and R and transmit is in binary(?) form - just as a stream of bits. I am uncertain if this is possible, because I guess it loses compatibility with the OpenSSL library. So we would need to reverse the process, constructing a signature using the S and R in the encoding OpenSSL will accept.

I have noticed that there is a `-binary` option in OpenSSL which gave me a blank file. I assumed I was on the wrong track.

Comment: R and S should be DER encoded. You could extract them and send them "raw" and re-encode them at the other end. In case either value is to small (probability is $2^{-8}=1/256$) you can zero-pad them to their maximal size (i.e. the size of the curve). [See the bear for some details](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1797/23623)

Comment: Thank you, if decode/reencode works that would be great.

Still after looking at the article I am not sure about:
1) Is it really possible to decode from DER and get only S and R - how about the OpenSSL/other library metadata - is it nonexistent? If there is metadata, I am guessing it must be kept intact, but I would be quite happy if that is not the case. 2) Am I right to think that DER decoding a standard action, so I can just google it to find standard libs?

I would appreciate further elaboration greatly. I have limited experience on these kind of implementations.

Comment: 1) I'm not sure, I haven't done it yet. But you can look at what your DER decoder gives you and find out what you need (probably the two integers in the sequence that have the right size. If there is meta-data it is most likely going to be something like curve-information which you can restore on the other end (I assume). 2) Yes, [DER decoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinguished_Encoding_Rules) is a very standard operation and you'll have no problem finding decoders (I hope).

Answer (score 7):

I know it's old, but I've spent some time trying to figure out the same question lately, so here's an answer of sorts.

Let's assume you've created a signature like so:

```
$ openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private_secp160k1.pem foo.txt > sign.bin
```

Because the curve is 160 bits, the signature is two 20 byte numbers. By default, OpenSSL will have written it in ASN.1's binary DER format. Inspecting it, we should find at least 2 * 20 bytes:

```bash
$ xxd -i < sign.bin
0x30, 0x2d, 0x02, 0x14, 0x22, 0xd0, 0x8b, 0xc1, 0x0d, 0x0b, 0x7b, 0xff,
0xe6, 0xc1, 0x77, 0xc1, 0xdc, 0xc4, 0x2f, 0x64, 0x05, 0x17, 0x71, 0xc8,
0x02, 0x15, 0x00, 0xdd, 0xf4, 0x67, 0x10, 0x39, 0x92, 0x1b, 0x13, 0xf2,
0x40, 0x20, 0xcd, 0x15, 0xe7, 0x6a, 0x63, 0x0b, 0x86, 0x07, 0xb6
```

In this particular DER encoded signature, there's 47 bytes. A DER or PEM encoded signature can be inspected with OpenSSL's `asn1parse` command to find out what the bytes are:

```bash
$ openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in sign.bin
 0:d=0  hl=2 l=  45 cons: SEQUENCE          
 2:d=1  hl=2 l=  20 prim: INTEGER  :22D08BC10D0B7BFFE6C177C1DCC42F64051771C8
24:d=1  hl=2 l=  21 prim: INTEGER  :DDF4671039921B13F24020CD15E76A630B8607B6
```

In short, it says:

- At byte 0, there is a DER header of length 2, indicating a there's a SEQUENCE of elements to follow, with a total combined length of 45 bytes.
- At byte 2, there is a DER header of length 2, indicating an INTEGER element of length 20, the first element of the SEQUENCE (20 bytes are then printed in hex)
- At byte 24, there is a DER header of length 2, indicating an INTEGER element of length 21, the second element of the SEQUENCE (20 bytes are then printed in hex)

(The d=N just means "depth", so the two INTEGER elements have d==1, because they are part of a sequence.)

Pretty printing the raw bytes from earlier, one can recognize the elements:

```bash
$ xxd -i < sign.bin
0x30, 0x2d, # Sequence of length 45 to follow (45 == 0x2d)

0x02, 0x14, # Integer of length 20 to follow (20 == 0x14)
# Here come the 20 bytes:
0x22, 0xd0, 0x8b, 0xc1, 0x0d, 0x0b, 0x7b, 0xff, 0xe6, 0xc1, 
0x77, 0xc1, 0xdc, 0xc4, 0x2f, 0x64, 0x05, 0x17, 0x71, 0xc8,

0x02, 0x15, # Integer of length 21 to follow (21 == 0x15)
0x00,       # The first of the 21 integer bytes (see explanation below!)
# Here come the remaining 20 bytes
0xdd, 0xf4, 0x67, 0x10, 0x39, 0x92, 0x1b, 0x13, 0xf2, 0x40, 
0x20, 0xcd, 0x15, 0xe7, 0x6a, 0x63, 0x0b, 0x86, 0x07, 0xb6
```

So why is the second integer 21 bytes?

Integers in DER are two's complement, so if the first byte of the 20 byte integer is >0x7F, an extra 0x00 byte is prepended, that way the first bit is always 0. In other words, while R and S are 20 bytes numbers, encoding them to DER integers may take an extra byte.

In OpenSSL, the ECDSA_SIG type contains two BIGNUMs. So once you've decoded the DER bytes with `d2i_ECDSA_SIG`, you can access them with `yourSig->r` and `yourSig->s`, which will be <=20 bytes (for 160 bits curves).

It's also possible that R or S need less than 20 bytes, if their first most significant digits happen to be zero. You can find the number of bytes needed for each one with `BN_num_bytes`, and then write them to a regular byte array with `BN_bn2bin` for serialiazation.

```c
ECDSA_SIG* ecSig = d2i_ECDSA_SIG(NULL, derBuf, derBufSize);

int rBytes = BN_num_bytes(ecSig->r), // Number of bytes needed for R
    sBytes = BN_num_bytes(ecSig->s); // Number of bytes needed for S

// ...
unsigned char someBuffer[40] = {0};
BN_bn2bin( ecSig->r, someBuffer + 20 - rBytes ); // Place R first in the buffer
BN_bn2bin( ecSig->s, someBuffer + 40 - sBytes ); // Place S last in the buffer
```

On the receiving end, you would then simply recreate the ECDSA_SIG instance by setting its `r` and `s` members:

```c
ECDSA_SIG* ecSig = ECDSA_SIG_new();
BN_bin2bn( someBuffer,      20, ecSig->r );
BN_bin2bn( someBuffer + 20, 20, ecSig->s );
```

Comment: +1 for this, for helping me get to a similar position on a different (yet related) problem that I had.  For any future searchers, a fixed-length format for encoding the *R* and *S* values is *IEEE P1363*, which 'right-aligns' the bytes of *R* and *S* in two halves of a byte array, which might be relevant for anyone doing interop between Java (which uses ASN.1 DER) and C# (which uses IEEE P1363) -- see https://www.codeproject.com/kb/security/cryptointeropsign.aspx for more details...